# Proving convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n-2}}{n^x} $

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I want to prove that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac {\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n-2}}{n^x} $ is convergent for $x > \frac{1}{2}$, otherwise divergent.

I got by multiplying the equation by $ \frac {\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2}}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2}} $, which got me $\frac{4}{n^x\cdot(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2})}$.

I am lost on how to prove the convergence. Could someone please show me or give me a hint? I assume I would need to use one of the criterias for determining convergence?

Comment: Just a quick question: is the sum really beginning at $n=1$? What happens with the term $\sqrt{n-2}$ then? Do you define it as $i$?

Comment: @Scounged you are right, its beginning at $n = 2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** the general term is

$${4\over n^x\left(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2}\right)}$$

and it's equivalent at $+\infty$ to

$${2\over n^{x+{1\over 2}}}$$

And the series converges iff $x+1/2\gt 1$

Comment: I get this $ {4\over n^x\left(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2}\right)} $, I also get why it would be convergent in that case of x > 1/2, but I have trouble understanding how you got ${1\over n^{x+{1\over 2}}}$ from it?

Comment: I edited it's $4/n^{x+1/2}$ but it doesn't change the conclusion

Comment: @Mykybo close to infinity, $\sqrt{n\pm 2}$ is basically the same as $\sqrt{n}$, so close to infinity, the denominator is virtually indistinguishable from $2\cdot n^{x+1/2}$. The constant factor doesn't really matter much, though.